# Java FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile using in coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, lucee

I'm converting some java code to ColdFusion. I've figured out most of it except for this section:

```
String passKey = "D:\\tmp\\passbook\\key\\pass.p12";
String password = "";
String appleFile = "D:\\tmp\\passbook\\key\\AppleWWDRCA.pem";
String pathToTemplateDirectory = "D:/tmp/passbook/t";
PKSigningInformation pkSigningInformation = 
    PKSigningUtil.loadSigningInformationFromPKCS12FileAndIntermediateCertificateFile(passKey, password, appleFile);


byte[] passZipAsByteArray = PKSigningUtil.createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(pass, pathToTemplateDirectory, pkSigningInformation);
FileUtils.forceDelete(new File("D:\\workspace\\emms_maven\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\passbook\\new.pkpass"));
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("D:\\workspace\\emms_maven\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\passbook\\new.pkpass"),
        passZipAsByteArray);
```

On these lines I'm stuck. Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of `forceDelete` & `writeByteArrayToFile` in ColdFusion.  Any ideas?

```
FileUtils.forceDelete(new File("D:\\workspace\\emms_maven\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\passbook\\new.pkpass"));
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("D:\\workspace\\emms_maven\\src\\main\\webapp\\WEB-INF\\passbook\\new.pkpass"),
        passZipAsByteArray);
```

Comment: A) It'll be more helpful to others if you explain what part you're having difficulty with and why? B) Start with small steps. Convert one line of code at a time.

Comment: @Ageax Just Updated my question home im able to clear my question.

Comment: (Edit) When translating code, I usually try to figure out what the code is actually doing, then decide if there's a better way to write it in CF. Those two lines are just deleting a file, then writing binary to a file. Since CF has functions to delete and write files, I'm guessing you don't need to translate that at all. Just use regular file functions: FileDelete and FileWrite

Comment: Glad it helped! Thanks for posting the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines are just deleting a file, then writing binary to the same file. Since CF has functions to delete and write files, I just used its regular file functions:

```
<cfset passZipAsByteArray = {}>

<cfset passZipAsByteArray =  PKSigningUtil.createSignedAndZippedPkPassArchive(
pass, pathToTemplateDirectory, 
pkSigningInformation) />


<cffile action="write"
   file="#pathToTemplateDirectory#/#createUUID()#.pkpass"
    output="#passZipAsByteArray#">
```

Comment: Good catch on the forceDelete! All you need is `cffile action=write` or `FileWrite()` because it'll overwrite any existing file.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I submitted an edit to describe what you did to hopefully help others

Comment: Thank you so much  for your help @Ageax ..  i'll be more then happy if it will help some one.